# Echo part of a JSON string in PHP from a variable or object that returns a prepended response

Tags: php, json, json-rpc

This is what I get when echo a variable called `$SessionID`:

> string(76) "{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"a0440004cf00a89c25377c9cdsf357f50644eec46fd96"}"

I wish to only echo the "result" part of this data, i.e, a0440004cf00a89c25377c9cdsf357f50644eec46fd96.
How do I accomplish this?

I have already tried json_decode to no avail(it also echos the entire `$SessionID` as above without any change:

```
$decoded_data= json_decode($SessionID);
echo $decoded_data->result;
```

I have an inkling this might be because of the "string(76)" prepended to the response.

Comment: [Seems to be working fine for me](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce7d468aaaa34b457dd98f783c7f4c3964549226)

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
$decoded_data= json_decode($SessionID, true);
echo $decoded_data['result'];
```